Menelaus $\implies$ Intercept theorem?
Here is a proposed algebraic demonstration of Menelaus's Theorem
Let $A, B, C\in  \mathbb R^3\setminus \{0\}$ a basis of $(\mathbb R^3,+,.)$. In this basis, $$A=1.A+0.B+0.C; B=0.A+1.B+0.C; C=0.A+0.B+1.C$$Let $A_1,B_1,C_1$ belong respectively to $BC\setminus \{B,C\},AC\setminus \{A,C\},AB\setminus \{A,B\}$
In other words, three points such that $\exists \alpha, \beta, \gamma \in \mathbb R\setminus\{0,1\}$ $$A_1=0.A+\alpha. B+(1-\alpha ). C=\alpha (0.A+1.B+u.C)$$ $$ B_1=\beta(v.A+0.B+1.C)$$ $$C_1=\gamma(1.A+w.B+0.C)$$with $u=\frac{1-\alpha}{\alpha}, v=\frac{1-\beta}{\beta}, w=\frac{1-\gamma}{\gamma}$
And $$A_1,B_1,C_1 \text{ aligned }\iff det(A_1,B_1,C_1)=0$$$$\iff \begin{vmatrix}0 &v  & 1 \\1 & 0 & w \\u & 1 &0 \end{vmatrix}=0\iff 1+uvw=0$$

Let’s write this last result in a more classical way:
$A_1=\alpha. B+(1-\alpha ). C\implies \Bigl( A_1-B=(\alpha-1 ).(B-C) \textbf{ and }A_1-C=\alpha (B-C)  \Bigr) $
So, $$\frac{\overrightarrow{BA_1}}{\overrightarrow{CA_1}}=(-1)\frac{1-\alpha}{\alpha}=-u$$
Same for the others…
And finally, $$A_1,B_1,C_1 \text{ alignés }\iff \frac{\overrightarrow{BA_1}}{\overrightarrow{CA_1}}\times \frac{\overrightarrow{CB_1}}{\overrightarrow{AB_1}}\times \frac{\overrightarrow{AC_1}}{\overrightarrow{BC_1}}=1$$
$\blacksquare$(qed)

If I take up the demonstration that I proposed:$C_1=B+\gamma(A-B)$ so that $$\boxed{C_1\text{ point at infinity }\iff \gamma=\infty}$$ . And Menelaus then translates as$$B_1A_1\parallel AB\iff \frac{\overline{BA_1}}{\overline{CA_1}}=\frac{\overline{AB_1}}{\overline{CB_1}}$$ie Intercept theorem.

Question: I think the proof of Menelaus’ theorem is correct. What bothers me is the problems in $$\boxed{C_1\text{ point at infinity }\iff \gamma=\infty}$$  But it seems to work:$$\frac{\overrightarrow{AC_1}}{\overrightarrow{BC_1}}=\frac{\infty-1}{\infty}=1$$ How to make, if possible, this process fully mathematically valid? I thought about establishing a bijection between a projective line and $\mathbb R\cup\{\infty\}$; and to extend the arithmetic of $\mathbb R$ but I would need your help.
Best regards.

I edited and transformed Meneaüs to Menelaus (see wikipedia).
